# How to get subject of email from gmail using google API using python?

Tags: python, email, google-api, gmail-api

How to get the subject of a message using Gmail API using python?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you succeeded in getting a message?

Comment: I'm getting the label names but what I want is the subject of a message. I found out this from google docs. .https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) returns a list of messages.  Each message is a [Users.messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) resource

Pay load header contains subject

```
  "payload": {
    "partId": string,
    "mimeType": string,
    "filename": string,
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": string,
        "value": string
      }
    ],
```

> payload.headers[]  list    List of headers on this message part. For the top-level message part, representing the entire message payload, it will contain the standard RFC 2822 email headers such as To, From, and Subject.

There is python code on the google developer site which will help you get started [python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)

Comment: an anwer with a full code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55144261/3154274  (as the question is closed, I can post it as an answer here)