# Python: how to get the subject of an email from gmail API

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, gmail-api

Using Gmail API, how can I retrieve the subject of an email?

I see it in the raw file but it's qui cumbersome to retrieve it, and I am sure there should be a way to do it directly via the API.

```
messageraw= service.users().messages().get(userId="me", id=emails["id"], format="raw", metadataHeaders=None).execute()
```

It is the same question as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280695/how-to-get-subject-of-email-from-gmail-using-google-api-using-python) but it has been close even so I can't post a better answer than the one proposed.

Comment: user.messages.get() will return everything, including headers

Comment: payload.headers[] List of headers on this message part. For the top-level message part, representing the entire message payload, it will contain the standard RFC 2822 email headers such as To, From, and Subject.  [more info] (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentionned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44280970/3154274), the subject is in the `headers` from `payload`

```
 "payload": {
    "partId": string,
    "mimeType": string,
    "filename": string,
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": string,
        "value": string
      }
    ],
```

But this not available if you use `format="raw`". So you need to use `format="full"`.

Here is a full code:

```
# source  = https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python?authuser=2


# connect to gmail api 
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


def main():

    # create the credential the first time and save it in token.pickle
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    #create the service 
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    #*************************************
    # ressources for *get* email 
    # https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#get
    # code example for decode https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get 
    #*************************************

    messageheader= service.users().messages().get(userId="me", id=emails["id"], format="full", metadataHeaders=None).execute()
    # print(messageheader)
    headers=messageheader["payload"]["headers"]
    subject= [i['value'] for i in headers if i["name"]=="Subject"]
    print(subject)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 11):

Since this was the question I landed on, I just wanted to share what I found to solve my own issue.

I am used to work with the `email` module that gives you a neat interface to interact with messages. In order to parse the message that the gmail api gives you, the following worked for me:

```py
import email
import base64
messageraw = service.users().messages().get(
    userId="me", 
    id=emails["id"], 
    format="raw", 
    metadataHeaders=None
).execute()
email_message = email.message_from_bytes(
    base64.urlsafe_b64decode(messageraw['raw'])
)
```

You end up with an `email.Message` object and can access the metadata like `email_message['from']`.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I find it bizarre this isn't in the official documentation

Answer (score 0):

with this code reads all the content of the mail

```
resultado = service.users().messages().list(userId= 'me',q=q_str,labelIds= ['INBOX']).execute()
mensajes = resultado.get('messages', [])
print ("Mensaje:")
    for mensaje in mensajes[:1]:
        leer = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=mensaje['id']).execute()
        payload = leer.get("payload")
        header = payload.get("headers")
        for x in header:
            if x['name'] == 'subject':
                sub = x['value'] #subject
                print(sub)
        print(leer['snippet'])  #body
```

`q=q_str`, this is the filter. view the API documentation.