# Get list of emails (Sender's Email, Subject and Body) between given dates through Gmail API in Python

Tags: python, json, gmail-api

I am working on a project that requires a JSON file response through Gmail API which contains a list of all the emails (Sender's Info, Subject, and Body) between given dates. Then that JSON file will be processed as needed. 
I'm not sure how to generate a request that could provide me with the required JSON file using Gmail API through Python.
I'm a beginner, Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have gone through OAuth and built the service (if not, check [the quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)), you have to do the following:

- Call [users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list), using the parameter `q` to filter your messages by date. This `q` uses the same syntax as in Gmail UI: see [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190). For example, if you wanted to retrieve your messages from the first 9 months in 2020, you would do this:

```
user_id = "me"
searchFilter = "after:2020/01/01 before:2020/10/01"
messages = service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, q=searchFilter).execute()
```

- When listing messages, only the `id` and the `threadId` are populated. In order to get the full message resource for all these messages, you should loop through them and call [users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get) for each message, using its `id`:

```
for message in messages["messages"]:
    messageId = message["id"]
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=messageId).execute()
```

- For each of these retrieved messages, you want to get the subject, body and sender's email. Subject and sender's email can be found on the message headers. You should loop through the headers and look for one named `Subject` and another one named `From`. See these answers for more info: [Python: how to get the subject of an email from gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55144261), [Get sender email from gmail-api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24781501). Regarding the body, it is to be found at `["payload"]["body"]`. See this answer: [How to retrieve the whole message body using Gmail API (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642129).

#### Reference:

- [Searching for Messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering)
- [REST Resource: users.messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages)
- [list(userId=*, labelIds=None, q=None, pageToken=None, maxResults=None, includeSpamTrash=None)](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#list)
- [get(userId=*, id=*, format=None, metadataHeaders=None)](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/python/latest/gmail_v1.users.messages.html#get)